# Find the maximum value of K such that sub-sequences A and B exist and should satisfy the mentioned conditions

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Given a string `S` of length `n`. Choose an integer `K` and two non-empty sub-sequences `A` and `B` of length `K` such that it satisfies the following conditions:

1. `A = B` i.e. for each `i` the `ith` character in `A` is same as the `ith` character in `B`.
2. Let's denote the indices used to construct `A` as `a1,a2,a3,...,an` where `ai belongs to S` and `B` as `b1,b2,b3,...,bn` where `bi belongs to S`. If we denote the number of common indices in `A` and `B` by `M` then `M + 1 <= K`.

Find the maximum value of `K` such that it is possible to find the sub-sequences `A` and `B` which satisfies the above conditions.

Constraints:
`0 < N <= 10^5`

Things which I observed are:

- The value of `K = 0` if the number of characters in the given string are all distinct i.e `S = abcd`.
- `K = length of S - 1` if all the characters in the string are same i.e. `S = aaaa`.
- The value of `M` cannot be equal to `K` because then `M + 1 <= K` will not be true i.e you cannot have a sub-sequence `A` and `B` that satifies `A = B` and `a1 = b1, a2 = b2, a3 = b3, ..., an = bn`.
- If the string `S` is palindrome then `K = (Total number of times a character is repeated in the string if the repeatation count > 1) - 1`. i.e. `S = tenet` then `t` is repeated `2` times, `e` is repeated `2` times, Total number of times a character is repeated = `4`, K = `4 - 1 = 3`.

I am having trouble designing the algorithm to solve the above problem.

Let me know in the comments if you need more clarification.

Comment: Since K is only used as an upper bound, its maximum value is unlimited. K = infinity, and A = B = S.  You probably made a mistake in the question.

Comment: @MattTimmermans but K > M, so we can't have A = B = S

Comment: @MattTimmermans I think the question is to find that K for the given string

Comment: A naive algorithm would just try all distinct starting positions in the string, and see the num of identical consequent characters. Worst case it's O(n^3). Is this good enough, or you need to find the best algorithm?

Comment: @valdo Can you tell me in more brief how the naive algorithm will work?

Comment: @valdo I don't think it will be O(n^3) time complexity, he is dealing with subsequences not substrings

Comment: @MattTimmermans A and B are described as non-empty subsequences of length K. K is therefore bound at the length of S.

Comment: @SurajSharma did you see my corrected second answer?

Comment: I am still testing your solution on couple of test cases. Will let you know if I find any cases with wrong answers. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @גלעדברקן your algorithm is correct. Thanks man :)

Comment: That's great, glad to hear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe we are just looking for the closest equal pair of characters since the only characters excluded from A and B would be one of the characters in the pair and any characters in between.

Here's `O(n)` in JavaScript:

```js
function f(s){
  let map = {}
  let best = -1
  for (let i=0; i<s.length; i++){
    if (!map.hasOwnProperty(s[i])){
      map[s[i]] = i
      continue
    }
    best = Math.max(best, s.length - i + map[s[i]])
    map[s[i]] = i
  }
  return best
}

var strs = [
  "aabcde", // 5
  "aaababcd", // 7
  "aebgaseb", // 4
  "aefttfea",
// aeft fea
  "abcddbca",
// abcd bca,
  "a" // -1
]

for (let s of strs)
  console.log(`${ s }: ${ f(s) }`)
```

`O(n)` solution in `Python3`:

```py
def compute_maximum_k(word):
    last_occurences = {}
    max_k = -1
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if(not last_occurences or not word[i] in last_occurences):
            last_occurences[word[i]] = i
            continue
        max_k = max(max_k,(len(word) - i) + last_occurences[word[i]])
        last_occurences[word[i]] = i
    return max_k

def main():
    words = ["aabcde","aaababcd","aebgaseb","aefttfea","abcddbca","a","acbdaadbca"]
    for word in words:
        print(compute_maximum_k(word))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The algorithm is not correct because `K = 7` for `aefttfea` but the algorithm is giving `4` and `K = 7` for `abcddbca` but the algorithm is giving `4`. The algorithm you described in the previous post by making a change in LCS recurrence relation is giving the rght answer but its exponential and when I do memoization the space complexity is high under the given constraints. Let me think of something to reduce the memoization space. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Length of string `<= 10^5`

Comment: No I said that in case of palindromes the answer is `(Sum of total number of time each character is repeated if its repeatation count > 1) - 1`. So for string `aefttfea`, `number of times a is repeated = 2, number of times e is repeated = 2, number of times f is repeated = 2, number of times t is repeated = 2`, `Sum of all this values is 8`. Answer would be `8  - 1 = 7`. Same goes for the string `abcddbca`.

Comment: I have explained the case of palindromes in the problem description.

Answer (score 2):

(Update: see `O(n)` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59335609/2034787).)

We can modify the classic [longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) recurrence to take an extra parameter.

JavaScript code (not memoised) that I hope is self explanatory:

```js
function f(s, i, j, haveUncommon){
  if (i < 0 || j < 0)
    return haveUncommon ? 0 : -Infinity
    
  if (s[i] == s[j]){
    if (haveUncommon){
      return 1 + f(s, i-1, j-1, true)
      
    } else if (i == j){
      return Math.max(
        1 + f(s, i-1, j-1, false),
        f(s, i-1, j, false),
        f(s, i, j-1, false)
      )
    } else {
      return 1 + f(s, i-1, j-1, true)
    }
  }
    
  return Math.max(
    f(s, i-1, j, haveUncommon),
    f(s, i, j-1, haveUncommon)
  )
}

var s = "aabcde"

console.log(f(s, s.length-1, s.length-1, false))
```

Comment: Can you explain how the algorithm is working? What is the idea?

Comment: What is the significance of the variable `haveUncommon `

Comment: @SurajSharma the additional conditions added to the LCS recurrence consider what to do if we are at a juncture where we could switch the `haveUncommon` state. If we don't yet have one and `i == j`, we have to consider that choosing to mark this spot as part of the solution could result in an invalid one, so we add branches to the recursion to allow us to find at least one place where `Ai == Bi` and `i != j`.

Comment: @SurajSharma (correcting my earlier comment) the problem conditions stipulate that A and B have at least one uncommon index (where `Ai == Bi and i != j`) since M + 1 cannot be greater than K.

Comment: The solution you gave has an exponential time complexity due to over-lapping sub-problems, I tried dynamic programming but getting wrong answers could you tell me the recursive equation and the base-case?

Comment: Actually I am still not able to understand how this problem is related to the LCS recursive equation?

Comment: @SurajSharma LCS finds the longest common subsequence between multiple strings. In this case we apply it to just *one* string since the problem you've described is asking for two subsequences in the same string. We seek to maximise K, which is the length of the subsequences (they are asked to be of equal length). We need to modify the usual recurrence because it could admit a solution that has all matching `i` and `j` (especially since we are  comparing subsequences within the same string).

Comment: @SurajSharma the algorithm I proposed has `O(n^2)` search space. The recursion would need to be either [memoised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) or converted to bottom-up, which could be more efficient depending on the input.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, as in your recursive solution if I try to memoize the solutions to the sub-problems using `O(n^2) space` still there is a problem when you are referring to the solution of sub-problem which is already solved because when I execute the function for the first time, the value of `haveUncommon` is `false` but as soon as the value of `haveUncommon` is `true` the solution to the same sub-problem changes. How can I take care of those scenarios? You can refer to my source-code: https://pastebin.com/HYtJejWb

Comment: @SurajSharma it seems to me that either memoisation or bottom-up will need a three-parameter space, `[i][j][haveUncommon]`, where `haveUncommon` is a boolean. Technically this results in `O(2 * n^2) = O(n^2)` space. As you suggested, the results for any pair of instances of the memoised values that differ only in `haveUncommon` indeed have different meaning and would need to be recorded separately.

Comment: Can we optimize the space? As I was analyzing the problem I came across some of the trivial cases: 1. When the string `S` has all different characters then answer would be `0`. 2. When the string `S` has all same characters then the answer would be `length of string - 1`. 3. When the string `S` is palindrome then the answer would be `Total number of times a characters is repeated - 1`.

Comment: As you deleted your post, the explanation is as follows: For string `S = aefttfea`,  `A = aeftfea` and `B = aeftfea`, in both the sub-sequences `t` is chosen from different indexes. `t` in `A` is chosen from `index = 3` and `t` in `B` is chosen from `index = 4`.

Comment: @SurajSharma second answer fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for the maximum length **substring** would be the following:

After building a [Suffix Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) you can derive the [LCP Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array). The maximum value in the LCP array corresponds to the K you are looking for. The overall complexity of both constructions is `O(n)`.

A suffix array will sort all prefixes in you string S in ascending order. The longest common prefix array then computes the lengths of the longest common prefixes (LCPs) between all pairs of consecutive suffixes in the sorted suffix array. Thus the maximum value in this array corresponds to the length of the two maximum length substrings of S.

For a nice example using the word "banana", check out the [LCP Array Wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array)

Comment: Can you tell me how the algorithm will work say for example if `S = anxa`.

Comment: Sure: the suffix array will be [3, 0, 1, 2] (meaning ["a", "anxa", "nxa", "xa"]) and the LCP that you can derive from that is [0, 1, 0, 0] which tells you "a" and "anxa" have a common prefix of length 1.

Comment: So the maximum value of `K = 1` for `S =  anxa`. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't the question require sub*sequence* not sub*string*? E.g. "baa" is a subsequence of "banana" but not a substring.

Comment: @myrtlecat Indeed, thanks for pointing that out. I will highlight that in my answer.

Comment: @SaiBot As the solution is for substring not for sub-sequence and as substring are a special case of subsequence, how would I change the solution for sub-sequence case?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think suffix arrays will help you for subsequences. You will need to use dynamic programming.

Comment: @myrtlecat Could you give me some idea that how can I think of a solution using `dynamic programming`. Is the answer given on the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/59306384/12210908 is correct as he doesn't gave the correctness proof of the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my previous answer as I don't think we need an LCS-like solution (LCS=longest Common Subsequence).

It is sufficient to find the couple of subsequences (A, B) that differ in one character and share all the others.

The code below finds the solution in O(N) time.

```
def function(word):
  dp = [0]*len(word)
  lastOccurences = {}

  for i in range(len(dp)-1, -1, -1):
    if i == len(dp)-1:
        dp[i] = 0
    else:
        if dp[i+1] > 0:
            dp[i] = 1 + dp[i+1]
        elif word[i] in lastOccurences:
            dp[i] = len(word)-lastOccurences[word[i]]

    lastOccurences[word[i]] = i
  return dp[0]
```

`dp[i]` is equal to `0` when all characters from i to the end of the string are different.

I will explain my code by an example.

For `"abcack"`, there are two cases:

- Either the first `'a'` will be shared by the two subsequences `A` and `B`, in this case the solution will be = `1 + function("bcack")`
- Or `'a'` will not be shared between `A` and `B`. In this case the result will be `1 + "ck"`. Why `1 + "ck"` ? It's because we have already satisfied `M+1<=K` so just add all the remaining characters. In terms of indices, the substrings are [0, 4, 5] and [3, 4, 5].

We take the maximum between these two cases.

The reason I'm scanning right to left is to not have O(N) search for the current character in the rest of the string, I maintain the index of the last visited occurence of the character in the dict `lastOccurences`.

Comment: The algorithm is not giving the correct answers for cases `aaababcd
`, `aebgaseb`. `K` output for `aaababcd` is `6` rather it should be `7` and `K` output for `aebgaseb` is `3` rather it should be `4`.